# ¿Cúal es el objetivo de relacionar tablas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

soy estudiante de Ingenieria de Sistemas, actualmente estoy viendo Base de Datos pero hay algo que no logro entender y es el **Porque** de relacionar tablas, mi profesor nos coloco un ejemplo: Se tiene una tabla llamada Contactos y otra llamada Generos y nos dice que al momento de guardar un contacto se buscara en la tabla genero, los generos (valga la redundancia) registrados en esa tabla para realizar el registro solo con los generos que se colocan en la tabla Generos, y para que, si por alguna razon se agrega un nuevo genero a la tabla, este nuevo genero aparezca por ejemplo en el combobox de una pagina web sin necesidad de modificar el codigo fuente de esta.

bueno, y otra pregunta seria, cual es la forma correcta de relacionar tablas y usarlas en el combobox de un formulario de registro por ejemplo.

De antemano, Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: el ejemplo parece ser bastante claro....lo importante es lo llamado **integridad relacional**. En efecto lo que se busca es evitar que hayan datos sin sentido...como por ejemplo, algún contacto con un género que no existe, o alguna transacción de un cliente que no existe, etc

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo entendi, pero  cual es la forma correcta de relacionar tablas y usarlas en el combobox de un formulario de registro por ejemplo

Comment: Ah, bueno, esa es una pregunta completamente diferente

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que comenta @Lamak las tablas se suelen relacionar por un ID numérico aunque también podría ser alfanumérico. A través de este ID, se relaciona una tabla con la otra. P.ej: Imagina que tienes una tabla personas y otra tabla perros, si cada id del perro se lo asocias a una persona, podrás obtener los perros que tiene cada persona. Espero te sirva :)

Comment: Gracias, he aclarado mis dudas sobre el porque se debe hacer, pero como le comente a @Lamak, cual es la forma correcta de relacionar tablas y usarlas en el combobox de un formulario de registro?

Comment: @AlanCan Realmente hay muchas formas de realizar eso y actualmente es otra pregunta totalmente distinta a la original. Ahora mismo seguramente se cerrará por "ser muy amplia". Te recomiendo investigar sobre como mandar información de un formulario a PHP y viceversa. También conectarte desde PHP a una base de datos mysql (entiendo que usarás MySQL). Cuando tengas algo desarrollado vuelve aquí con las dudas que tengas, porque ahora habría un montón de respuestas diferentes y todas serían válidas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FranciscoRomero, lo hare!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relacionar tablas basicamente se hace para cuidar la integridad de datos, hay algunos datos que le pueden corresponder a mas de un registro:
 Si tengo 100 empleados todos trabajando en la misma sucursal quiero tener los datos de la sucursal 1 vez, no una por cada empleado. Por lo cual relacionaria la tabla de empleados a la de sucursales. Cada empleado solo tendria el ID de la sucursal, esta seria una relacion de 1 a muchos. 
Otro motivo por el cual se hace tambien es que los motores de bases de datos crean indices para almacenar estar relaciones y estos sirven de manera muy importante a la hora de optimizar las consultas. Ademas de realizar checkeos de integridad para que no queden registros huerfanos ( empleados con ids de sucursales que no existen, por ejemplo ) a la hora de insertar o eleminar registros.

Answer (score 1):

Las tablas relacionales soy muy importantes y ayuda en el control de los datos, la información va en cascada, y no te permite eliminar los datos que tiene dependencia, Ej. si creaste un producto y ya tiene una venta, si la relacionas bien, no puedes eliminar ese producto a menos que elimines la venta, también puedes relacionar la descripción, para que no se cambie, porque si lo hacen, pasaría que vendieron un collar de oro y luego cambian la descripción a collar de cobre. Relacionar tablas te da seguridad y mas seriedad a tus datos, es como poner una llave contra usuarios que utilizan malas practicas.
Y hay un sin fin de ventajas..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Porque relacionar tablas?

Porque las tablas por separado solo representan un agrupamiento/categorización de datos y en conjunto contienen información relevante para el cliente que la solicita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Queremos saber a que marca es cada producto por lo cual la información en la tabla "Proveedores" tiene que estar anotada tambien en la tabla "NOTEBOOK".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PERO OJO! estas tablas no están relacionadas, solo se agrego un campo y se tipió
a mano.Cumple la función ? si , pero la integridad de los datos esta comprometida ya que si el día de mañana (en el mas simple ejemplo) Nokia es absorbido por Lenovo tendríamos que ir 1 x 1 cambiando el registros.
Como lo resolvemos ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Manipular la información ahora es mucho mas fácil.

Pero mejor pregunta creo yo es :

Porque separamos la información en diferente Tablas?

Para que no solo la información este bien organizada sino que la misma pueda ser manipulada, escalada y consultada a medida que el sistema crece como tambien las necesidades de la empresa. No es lo mismo tener 7 productos a tener 139 mil, por lo cual una sola hoja con todos los datos seria inviable.

Answer (score 0):

Relacionas las tablas **para mantener la consistencia de los datos**, cada tabla es un grupo de datos que posiblemente no tiene sentido absoluto con una única tabla, al relacionarla con otras tablas empieza a tenerlo. Las relaciones es un **mecanismo de restricción** de dependencia de los dato con otras tablas, por ejemplo **puede evitar borrar datos** de una tabla padre sin borrar los datos de las tablas hijas y así **evitamos tener registros huérfanos**.